# Schedule Azure Function according to weekday

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-functions

I want to schedule my Azure Function as :
`11:00 AM  for Monday to Friday , 2:30 AM for Saturday & Sunday`

How can I write cron expression for this?

Please help.

Comment: I found https://bradymholt.github.io/cron-expression-descriptor/ useful for Azure function crons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately you would need to have two azure functions

```
public static void RunMonFriday([TimerTrigger("0 0 11 * * 1-5")]TimerInfo 
myTimer, ILogger log) { 
   // Call method to job
}
public static void RunSatSun([TimerTrigger("0 30 2 * * 6-7")]TimerInfo m
yTimer, ILogger log){
   // Call method to job
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [Invoke Azure function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass) with enviroment in your pipeline.

Here is an example:

[image]

Configure [schedule in your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure devops.
Here is an example:

```
    # YAML file in the main branch
schedules:
- cron: "0 0 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
- cron: "0 12 * * 0"
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build
  branches:
    include:
    - master
```